# Finding the Cross-Section of two List views in one Django template

Tags: python, django

I have two models that feed one view.

*models.py*

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(Item_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    owned_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)****
    added_at = models.DateTimeField('date item added')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('last update')
    def __str__(self):
      return self.item_name

class Item_status(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    loaned_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    due_back = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    def __time__(self):
     return self.loaned_at
    def itemname(self):
      return (self.item.item_name)
```

I have the following view

*views.py*

```
class LoanedItemsByUserListView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = Item_status
    template_name ='catalog/item_status_list_borrowed_user.html'
     paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self):
    return Item_status.objects.filter(borrower=self.request.user).order_by('due_back')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(LoanedItemsByUserListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['Owned_list'] = Item.objects.filter(owned_by=self.request.user, item_type = 1)
    context['Loaned_list'] = Item_status.objects.exclude(borrower=self.request.user).exclude(borrower__isnull=True)
    return context
```

I would like to find the cross section of the 'Owned_list' and the 'Loaned_list' in a single template

Something like

```
<h2>Loaned Books</h2>
{% if Owned_list %}
<ul>
  {% for thing in Owned_list.item_name and in Loned_list.item.item_name %}
<li>
      {{thing}}
</li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul
 {% else %}
  <p>There are no books in the library.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I have take a look at the django documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/, and around SO but not found exactly what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Its not clear what do you want to achieve. Can show it with an example?

Comment: Sure, I am looking to produce a list that contains values that are contained in both the Owned_list, which is anything in an Items db table owned by the current user, and also the Loaned_list which are records in an Item_status table where the borrower is not null or the current user.  

The SQL would look like this 
    `SELECT item_name FROM item i 
    JOIN item_status itst
    ON i.id = itst.item_id
    WHERE itst.borrower_id is not null and itst.borrower_id <> 
    "current_user_id"  and i.owned_by_id = "current_user_id"`

Comment: UPDATE : I have resolved this with the following modification to my view
`context['Loaned_list'] =Item_status.objects.filter(item__owned_by=self.request.user).exclude(borrower=self.request.user).exclude(borrower__isnull=True)
        return context`